# Emgu.cv DetectorParameters.GetDefault() returns a System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, emgucv, access-violation

I'm working on a project that uses emgu.cv to detect arUco markers. When trying to use or test the following code, I get a System.AccessViolationException:

```
DetectorParameters detectorParams = DetectorParameters.GetDefault();
```

Based on other suggestions, I've made sure that the configurations for all projects are set to x64, tried to set my own defaults, this made it so tests would run, but I then get a SEHException.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

net5.0

Emgu.CV version 4.4.0.4099

Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.dldt version 4.4.0.4099

Comment: Hi, try this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351563/aruco-detectmarkers-implementation-emgu-c-sharp

Comment: I reached out to emgu about this and they said it was a bug on their end. They released an update that fixed the issue on 7/4/2021:
https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/525